# QGIS 3.4.4 Crash on vertex editor

Tags: qgis-3

I've just installed QGIS 3.4.4. Each time I edit any layer, as soon as I select the vertex editor (single shapefile) I receive the 'unknown exception error'. The error then occurs with ANY edit in any layer. QGIS then crashes.

I have checked in ArcGIS and the shapefiles are clean. I have tried creating new (clean) projects with new (clean) shapefiles of just a simple two-node line but nothing fixes this error. Every shapefile I create or download is faced with the same issues.

I'm stuck - any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have previous versions installed? How did you installed QGIS 3.4.4 (stand-alone or network installer)?

Comment: No. I just did a standard install: http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: Crash report: Crash ID: 6db1b9d6d539af58f60b41cae447e495b7c96ff7
QgsPointLocator::~QgsPointLocator :
QgsPointLocator::~QgsPointLocator :
QgsSnappingUtils::clearAllLocators :
QgsSnappingUtils::~QgsSnappingUtils :
QgsVectorLayerProperties::`default constructor closure' :
QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren :
QWidget::~QWidget :
CPLStringList::operator[] :
main : BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :
QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.4.4-Madeira
QGIS code revision: af723c4942
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
Running against Qt: 5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL: 2.4.0
Running against GDAL: 2.4.0

Comment: I can't reproduce it here with the same install. Try with a clean profile, deleting the `%AppData%\QGIS` folder.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! I had tried a clean install which didn't help. I have now tried a clean install using 3.0.0 and this has solved it. Thank's for your assistance!

Comment: I regret that you have not been able to solve the problem with the installation of version 3.4.4. Many bugs were fixed since version 3.0.0. I think the right thing to do would be to close your question with the reason: 'This problem can not be reproduced'.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. A bug report was already open. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21307

Comment: Fixed in the new 3.4.5 LTR and 3.6.0 versions.